# How to parse xml with qt?

Tags: c++, html, xml, qt

I'm trying to parse a html page with qt using QtXmlQuery, with:

```
query.setFocus(qNetworkReply->readAll());
```

but I receive the following error message:

```
Error FODC0002 in tag:trolltech.com,2007:QtXmlPatterns:QIODeviceVariable:u, 
 at line 3, column 44: Entity 'ndash' not declared.
```

I think it means the html page I'm trying to read is malformed. How to fix the page ?

Comment: Your problem is that HTML isn't XML. You need an HTML parser.

Comment: So what tools are available to me ? Maybe I could just use a tool to transform html into xhtml, as much as possible, and then use the xml tools, or should I use something different ? This just seems a simple header error xml issue though, where does this ndash come from and how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

first maybe check if the ndash is declared in your xml:

```
<!ENTITY ndash "&#8211;"> <!-- en dash, U+2013 ISOpub --> 
<!ENTITY mdash "&#8212;"> <!-- em dash, U+2014 ISOpub -->
```

Named entities, also known as internal entities in the XML specifications, are what you usually refer to when you talk about "entities." You declare them in either the DTD or the internal subset (that is, as part of the  statement in your document) and use them in your document as references. During the XML document parsing, the entity reference is replaced by its representation.
In plain English, these entities are simply macros that get expanded when you process your document.

example:

```
<!DOCTYPE article PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD Journal
Publishing DTD v3.0 20080202//EN" "journalpublishing3.dtd"
[<!ENTITY ndash "&#x2013;">]
```

[see here for more info](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-entities/)

If everything is OK then alternatively try something else: you can use the builtin QtWebKit. 
Example:

```
class MyPageLoader : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  MyPageLoader();
  void loadPage(const QUrl&);

public slots:
  void replyFinished(bool);

private:
  QWebView* m_view;
};

MyPageLoader::MyPageLoader()
{
  m_view = new QWebView();

  connect(m_view, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)),
          this, SLOT(replyFinished(bool)));
}

void MyPageLoader::loadPage(const QUrl& url)
{
  m_view->load(url);
}

void MyPageLoader::replyFinished(bool ok)
{
  QWebElementCollection elements = m_view->page()->mainFrame()->findAllElements("a");

  foreach (QWebElement e, elements) {
    // Process element e
  }
}
```

To use the class

```
MyPageLoader loader;
loader.loadPage("http://www.google.com")
```

you can also find some wraper [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sgml-for-qt/)

to retrieve element:

```
QWebView* view = new QWebView(parent);
view.load(QUrl("http://www.your_site.com"));
QWebElementCollection elements = view.page().mainFrame().findAllElements("a");
```

Comment: Wait if I already have the html in a QByteArray, could I skip all these steps ? It seems to be a fairly big amount of code. Plus, how can I retrieve a part of the page, using Xpath, which is what I'm looking for in the first place ? I'm trying to set a QXmlQuery, but I get the error I mentioned when trying to set its focus. Maybe I could just change the page slightly to make the setFocus work ?

Comment: well I am not sure, this is a way that works to load page, see edit how to retrieve element

Comment: It seems  interesting but it's a lot of refactoring to insert that into my own code. I'm sure there's a way to combine both our solutions, but I don't really know QWebView. But does findAllElements really work with any complicated xpath ?

Comment: I haven't tried it but probably this only works if the HTML was loaded from the web. [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086247/parsing-html-with-c-using-qt-preferably)

Comment: I see. But I just looked at findAllElements, and it just addresses CSS path, not general xpath. I would really like to handle my page just like a xml document. Any idea how to translate my html into xhtml compliant, or to just fix the issue that I'm talking about in my question ? I'm sure it's just a stupid header issue, but I don't understand the error message

Comment: @shkra19 maybe check if the ndash is declared in your xml: <!ENTITY ndash   "&#8211;"> <!-- en dash, U+2013 ISOpub -->
<!ENTITY mdash   "&#8212;"> <!-- em dash, U+2014 ISOpub -->  [see here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-entities/)

Comment: No it doesn't appear to be there, where to add it into the document (beginning, middle, end ?), and how, given that the document is stored into a QByteArray?

Comment: To the very beginning ? I tried it, but I get the following error: at line 1, column 10: Expected '-' or 'DOCTYPE', but got 'ENTITY'.

Comment: Wait, I'm a bit lost. Where am I to add the ndash declaration exactly ? I tried adding it in the beginning of the document, but as I said, I get an error. The document starts with the html tag. I also tried adding an xml header, such as  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> but I get the following error: "Opening and ending tag mismatch."

Answer (score 0):

Note that the Qt documentation about XSLT 2.0 clearly says that only XML entities are supported.

> The QtXmlPatterns implementation of the XPath Data Model does not include entities (due to QXmlStreamReader not reporting them). This means that functions unparsed-entity-uri() and unparsed-entity-public-id() always return negatively.

Source: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/xmlprocessing.html#xslt-2-0

They do not specify a way to "fix" (go around) the problem. One way to fix the problem is to read your document as a string and replace all HTML entities to the hexadecimal syntax or even replace with the corresponding Unicode character so that way the parser will be happy.

A slow way to do it, but to prove the point:

```
doc.replace("&ndash;", QChar(8211));
```

A better way would be to have the entities defined somewhere, but I'm not so sure there is really a way to do that.

Note that the [QXmlStreamReader](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qxmlstreamreader.html#setEntityResolver) itself has a function to setup the entity resolver, but I don't think you ever have access to that class. Hence the comment about the QtXmlPatterns not supporting entities.